# Java TCP/IP Server - Client Communication over the internet

Tags: java, tcp, ip

I'd like to get a tcp/ip connection working over the internet. I already have two classes, one tcpserver which handles requests and a tcpclient which connects, sends and receives data.

Until now I had it working perfectly on local networks. The usual 127.0.0.1 / localhost and my 192.168.xxx.xxx adresses are not giving any problems.

My question is, what do I have to do to make it work over the internet. As I might want to do some research involving a simple http/server I need this to work.

I doubt its my firewall but maybe its the ISP that blocks this type of connection. Anybody has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open a port in the router that leads to the one that the server is listening on. You then connect to your public IP. This ip can be found on http://www.visaminip.se/

Comment: Please look at my code (its multithreading of course ;) :

tcpcserver t = new tcpserver(8000);
Thread.sleep(100);
tcpclient c = new tcpclient("31.151.xxx.xxx",8000);

I run this on the same computer in the same project. But just like a unit-test this should work, right? Or maybe its that I cannot connect to my own computer through internet.

Comment: You should connect to your modem/router using your gateway address. Open command promt, type ipconfig. Look up "standard gateway" and enter that in your browser. That will promt a loginwindow and you need to enter your credentials. If you haven't changed those it's usually: login = admin, password = 1234 or password or admin. This is also printed in the manual. When you reach that page you can configure your router settings. Here you need to open up the port that your server is listening on

Answer (score 0):

To provide a service over the internet you need a public IP address. 10.x.x.x and 192.168.x.x are private networks. 127.x.x.x is for the local machine only.

The client can connect to the public IP address of a sepecific port.

The server's modem/router/firewalls allows this port to be open and passes traffic to your server on that port.

Comment: Thank you Peter, I already looked up my public IP by usings a 'retrieve-my-ip' website. It starts with 31.151.xxx.xxx so this is probably a public IP address right?

Comment: yes. And your client just needs internet access. The server on the other hand needs to have your firewalls setup to allow your port to be accessed.

Comment: I just disabled my firewall, although I shouldn't. Anyway I did some online port scanner checks and it said all the usual ports are not reachable. Maybe I could check my router settings for some port opening? If that's not the case it's probably my Internet Server Provider who is blocking all.

Comment: Some ISPs block common HTTP ports like port 80. You could try a different port instead.

Comment: Right now I'm writing an unit test for checking ports 1-8000 on my computer with my router firewall and pc firewall disabled so if this doesn't work it's probably my ISP. Anyone other knows a way of hosting a webserver on your own conputer?

Comment: Which ports are available is usually controlled by your modem. I would check its configuraton.

Comment: You should connect to your modem/router using your gateway address. Open command promt, type ipconfig. Look up "standard gateway" and enter that in your browser. That will promt a loginwindow and you need to enter your credentials. If you haven't changed those it's usually: login = admin, password = 1234 or password or admin. This is also printed in the manual. When you reach that page you can configure your router settings. Here you need to open up the port that your server is listening on

Comment: Thanks Jimmy and Peter, it works. I found it in the router settings under 'port forwarding'. Thanks for helping a young software engineer out :)